# Не понимаю почему пишет ошибку

Tags: javascript, html

Использую среду Brackets.io и на код выдает данные ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть кода просто открывать рандомную ссылку из массива, да и сам код работает, но смущает, что показывает ошибки.

```js
var sites = [
'../films/joker.html',
'../films/aquaman.html',
    '../films/parker.html',
    '../films/titanic.html'
];

function randomSite() {
    var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
    location.href = sites[i];
}
```

Comment: Это не ошибки, как таковые, а предупреждения. И переходите уже на const и let переменные

Comment: @SwaD, когда на остальных всё равно, то можно использовать const и let.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используй **Brackets** и переменные **Var**, они устарели!
Как я понял ты скорее всего обучаешься по старым видосам)
Лучше смотри видосы года минимум 2018 (Js тоже развивается)

В среде VsCode предупреждений нету. Удачи ;3